# Mapping XKB to custom shell command

Tags: gnome, bash, brightness, xkb

I'm running a crouton Gnome instance on a Pixelbook, and my brightness keys don't work in gnome. I have no /etc/default/grub file to speak of, so all those options aren't available to me. I'm thinking of seeing if I can workaround this situation by using xkb to remap the brightness up and down keys to the brightness up and brightness down commands on the shell.

Is there a way to do this?